# Creating trees in tcl

Tags: tree, tcl

I want to create an AVL tree in tcl. I read that in tcl we cannot have structures that contain references of themselves like in C.

```
struct tree{
    tree *treelink;
}
```

I want to be able to create the trees without using OTcl. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in luck. I wrote one for [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Tcl) a week or so ago. The code is long enough that I'm not repeating it here, but feel free to take it and adapt.
I wouldn't use it in production though. Arrays and dictionaries provide the same key abstract operations (insertion, deletion, lookup, update, enumeration) and work just fine with their built-in implementation.

Comment: The license on that code is formally GFDL due to it being on RC, but I give permission to consider it to be under the Tcl-flavor BSD license as well.

Comment: Oh it was you who wrote that code. Thanks a bunch. You are awesome!! But the problem i had with that was with the "package require TclOO" which gives the error "can't find package TclOO" in ubuntu. I havent been quite able to install it correctly.

Comment: @Chhama The code should be relatively easy to adapt to Itcl, XOTcl or Snit; it's not really using anything very fancy (the fanciest bit? the special root `nil` sentinel, which is just a particular object).

Comment: Thanks, I installed tcl 8.6 and the code runs successfully with it. I'll have to reinstall ns2 with tcl 8.6 and I think I'll be OK. Thanks again.